# Node.js Loading css

Tags: css, node.js

My folders:

```
server.js
index.html
-public
 --css
  --ses.scss
  --style.css
```

Server js:

```
var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var publicPath = path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var fs = require('fs');

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
        res.sendfile('./index.html');

    });
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/ses.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
```

CSS works when I open index.html with google chrome without server.When I use node.js CSS isn't loading.

Comment: I don't think an scss file can be loaded directly into html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node :

```
app.use("/css",express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
```

css :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ses.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Welcome Bro :) .

Answer (score 1):

`express.static()` serves the *contents* of its folder directly on the root.

Therefore, `public/` is not part of the URL.

Comment: So, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: @dandadadadan: Use a path relative to the directory (`/css/...`).